# IF statement move data to another sheet but only certain range

Tags: vba, excel

Please can you advise how I tweak the below code to only move row data for columns A:H?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = 11 Then
  If Target = "Complete" Then
   nxtRw = Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & nxtRw)
     Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
     Application.EnableEvents = True
     ElseIf Target.Column = 11 Then
  If Target = "Cancelled" Then
   nxtRw = Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & nxtRw)
     Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
     Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
 End If
 End If
End Sub
```

At the moment it moves the whole row over. in the sheet it moves to I have additional validation lists in rows I,J,K which it removes when it copies over.

Any help is much appreciated

thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Resize property. You can also shorten your If slightly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 11 Then
    If Target = "Complete" Then
        nxtRw = Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 8).Copy Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & nxtRw)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf Target = "Cancelled" Then
        nxtRw = Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 8).Copy Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & nxtRw)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```